# PHP json_encode() gives no value

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

```
if(isset($_POST["search"]) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $database = new Database; 
    $connection = $database -> connect(); 
    $sql = "SELECT surname, name, street, streetNumber FROM customers";     
    if(!$req = $connection -> prepare($sql)){
        echo "e001";
    }else{
        $req -> execute();
        $res = $req -> get_result();

        $json = array();

        while($row= $res -> fetch_assoc()){
            $json['customers:'] = $row;
        }
        print json_encode($json);       
        $req -> close();
        $database -> disconnect($connection);
    }
}
```

As far as I see this code is pretty much like it's tought here on stack overflow.

So I don't understand why I just won't get a response when I request this via AJAX and look at the network tab in Chrome debug.

Everything works, all the scripts run on, I don't get any errors, just an empty response.

EDIT:
Oh, and i tried, i get data from the database with that funcition, tried by echoing without json_encode(), so that can't be the problem.

EDIT: Asked for JS code, doesn't do anything with the response yet since i view the response in the browser.

```
function loadCustomers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/backend/customers.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'search': "Schramm"
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response, status) {},
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        },
    });
}
```

EDIT: The database and tables are set to `UTF-8` so it isn't an encoding problem.

Comment: What does `json_last_error` say? Charsets/encoding?

Comment: offtopic: `$json['customers:'] = $row;` this will overwrite values on every iteration, you'll only get the last row, anyway, you should add the pertinent jquery code here also

Comment: Did you try an `else` or check that `search` and `username` are set? Also why would you put `:` in property name , not very friendly in javascript?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm pretty new to all of it, it's a learning project.

Comment: @mario The table and database are encoded UTF-8

Comment: well the obvious place that nothing gets returned is when `if()` conditions aren't met

Comment: @charlietfl I can conidently say that they are met, i debugged that already

Comment: @Ghost Thanks for the info